# Третий брат - Иван, учится... Так ли было у Горького?

Tags: приложение

А.Н. Гвоздев. Очерки по стилистике русского языка. Синтаксис

§ 476. 6) У приложений, обозначающих фамилии и имена и стоящих после существительного, обособление, направляя внимание на приложение, обычно указывает на то, что фамилия сообщается впервые; отсутствие обособления указывает на то, что фамилия уже знакома слушателям и поэтому не требует подчеркивания:

Заведующий складом, Петров, согласился отпустить товары — Заведующий складом Петров согласился отпустить товары; Переводчик, князь Тарханов, подошел к Хаджи Мурату (Л. Толстой, Хаджи Мурат); Хозяин сакли, Садо, был человек лет сорока (там же); Ему помогал торговать Алексей — ленивый, грубый парень; Третий брат — Иван, учится в учительском институте... (Горький, Мои университеты).

Непонятно последнее предложение. Иван - это приложение? Третий брат - подлежащее?

учится - сказуемое?

По-моему, приложение, выраженное собственным именем, выделяется либо запятыми, либо тире.

на сайте http://www.kniga.com/books/preview_txt.asp?sku=ebooks172840 Горький в "Мои университеты":

Третий брат, Иван, учился в Учительском институте и, живя там в интернате, бывал дома только по праздникам, - это был маленький, чисто одетый, гладко причесанный человечек, похожий на старого чиновника.

Есть в Интернете и с тире перед "Иван", как у А.Н. Гвоздева в "Очерках по стилистике русского языка".

Так как же правильно?

Answer (score 5):

1) Третий брат, Иван, учился в Учительском институте.... Здесь Иван - приложение со значением уточнения, обычно обособляется  запятыми, реже для более распространенного приложения используется тире.

Сравнить:Третий брат – Иван Шувалов – Петру и Александру был не родным, а двоюродным.

2) Третий брат — Иван, (он) учится в учительском институте... Нестандартный и не очень удачный вариант, можно предположить, что это два предложения в составе БСП, второе предложение неполное.

3) Заведующий складом Петров согласился отпустить товары.

В книге Гвоздева информация сомнительная, скорее всего именно в этом случае мы о Петрове узнаем впервые, нам просто называют должность (приложение) и фамилию лица.

4) Заведующий складом, Петров, согласился отпустить товары. Это уточнение с разными мотивами: или это просто дополнительная информация, или мы уже что-то знаем о Петрове, или там были разные заведующие складом.